# When should I define a new array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I want to know which one is more optimized?

1. Defining several separated array
2. Using nested array keys

Here is an example:

```
function arr(){
    $arr1 = array();
    $arr2 = array();
    $arr3 = array();

    $arr1['key1'] = 'val1';
    $arr2['key1'] = 'val1';
    $arr3['key1'] = 'val1';

    return array($arr1, $arr2, arr3);
}
```

OR

```
function arr(){
    $arr = array();

    $arr['arr1']['key1'] = 'val1';
    $arr['arr2']['key1'] = 'val1';
    $arr['arr3']['key1'] = 'val1';

    return $arr1;
}
```

Actually I have not any problem, *I just want to know*, which approach is faster in php? nested key or separated array?!

Comment: Note that the two functions you've provided will give different results.

Comment: @AlexShesterov why you think the results will be different?

Comment: yes, your `array($arr1,...)` has different keys. you'll have `$arr[0]['key1']`, `$arr[1]['key2']`, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed set of keys, then create the whole array in a single statement, as below. It will be both the fastest and the most readable way.

```
function arr(){
    return array(
      array('key1' => 'val1'),
      array('key1' => 'val2'),
      array('key1' => 'val3'),
    );
}
```

Regarding the performance difference between the two ways — you may benchmark the two functions to find out, as Pamblam did. But the [difference will be so minimal that it will barely ever matter](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/).

Comment: Thanks, it was useful. also please remove the last `,` in the nested array.

Comment: @Sajad, note that PHP _allows_ an optional comma after the last array element, [see here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) It's a matter of taste whether to use it, and it doesn't affect the semantics of the program.

Comment: One advantage of using a comma after the last element is: comparing file versions in a version control system. If an additional element is added to the end of the array, the difference will be exactly that one added line if a comma was used. Without a comma, the difference will be the added line and the previous line with the missing comma added.